# Showing the Steps in Solving a Linear Equation

Tags: equations

I am trying to find some LaTeX code that would show the steps in solving a linear equation (NOT a system of linear equations). For example, to solve 3x-2y=-1, I want to write:

```
 3x - 2y = -1
-3x           - 3x
__________________
    - 2y = -3x - 1

    - 2y = -3x - 1
    -----  -------
      -2      -2

       y = 3x + 1
           --   --
            2    2
```

I'm sorry that I can't provide an MWE, because I don't know which LaTeX function to use.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you missing one or more horizontal rules? What's the spacing you're looking for?

Comment: @Ethan : have a look to "systeme", a nice package with a lot of examples easy to read.

Comment: @TH. - I think the OP was trying to provide a visual distinction between fraction bars (the dashed lines) and "ordinary" horizontal rules (the solid line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses the `array` package (and its `\newcolumntype` and `\extrarowheight` macros) and an `array` environment. Observe the (typographic) distinction between unary and binary uses of the `-` (minus) symbol.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{{}}c<{{}}} % for columns with binary and relational operators
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\displaystyle}r}

\begin{document}
\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\begin{array}{RCRCRCR}
 3x & - & 2y & = & \multicolumn{3}{R}{-1} \\
-3x &   &    &   & -3x \\
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{R}{-2y} & = & -3x & - &  1 \\[2.5ex]
\multicolumn{3}{R}{\frac{-2y}{-2}} & = & 
     \multicolumn{3}{R}{\frac{-3x-1}{-2}}\\[3ex]
& & y & = & \frac{3x}{2} & + & \frac{1}{2} \\
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```